# How to change colors of cells in Google visualization graph table

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am building a table in Google graphs.  I would like to change the color of a cell based on the numeric value of a cell. I am assuming I will do something like iterate through all of the cells and call the colorFormat object specified in docs here:  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#colorformatter

The problem is that there are no examples of exactly how to implement this method.

Does anyone know of an example or how the colorFormat can be implemented to change the color of cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#colorformatter - did you scroll farther down?

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
formatter.addRange(-20000, 0, 'white', 'orange');
formatter.addRange(20000, null, 'red', '#33ff33');
formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column
```

Comment: Is it possible to define a colour for a cell that is null?

Comment: Yes you can, if you look at the addRange it states: **from - [String, Number, Date, DateTime, or TimeOfDay] The lower boundary (inclusive) of the range, or null. If null, it will match -∞. String boundaries are compared alphabetically against string values.**, with the same for to. So you'd have but from and to as ```null```